# s3fs mount storage in Cloud (NOT amazon's)

Tags: amazon-s3, object-storage, s3fs

I am new to s3, object storage and linux.
I have a CentOS linux server and an active subscription to public cloud for object storage. Now I want to connect and mount the cloud object storage to the linux server.
I have installed fuse s3fs to the linux server, I have added the access and secret access key to the password file..but I am missing where I should set the endpoint. I know that by default it points to amazon's s3 but I want to use a different service and I cannot find where I should set the endpoint. Any help would be appreciated..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try running:

> s3fs <_bucket_name_> <_local_mount_point_> -o nocopyapi -o 
>   use_path_request_style -o nomultipart -o sigv2 -o 
>   url=http://s3-api.sjc-us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/ -d -f -o curldbg -of2 -o allow_other -o passwd_file=/etc/ibmcos.pwd

if that doesn't work for you, find out your endpoint url from the portal or look here:

> https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/endpoints

Comment: Not sure what is to be filled in for <_bucket_name_>. I created a bucket s3:/TEST, but when I use that it returns `s3fs: bucket name and path("s3://TEST") is wrong, it must be "bucket[:/path]".`

Comment: @Sören you don't need the `s3://` prefix, just bucket name only.